# How do I dynamically assign a value to an MVC grid based on the value from another column in the row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid

I have a dataset currently that has 4 columns for values lets call them odd_low, odd_high, and even_low, even_high and I want to have two columns in the grid (LOW and HIGH) and have the values set based on the value of another column which will simply be 'O' or 'E' - This column is named side

Here's a quick sample (right now the column is bound to the odd fields only)

```
 columns.Add(model => model.ODD_LOW).Titled("Low House #").Sortable(sortable);
columns.Add(model => model.ODD_HIGH).Titled("High House #").Sortable(sortable);
columns.Add(model => model.SIDE).Titled("Side").Sortable(sortable);
```

My guess is that I'll need to accomplish this using a script, but I'm not sure how to dynamically access the rows and fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for a dynamic datagrid in the scenario you discribed.

When using MVC, it's a good practice to use a ViewModel object to represent data. This way, your controller is resposible for getting the data from your business / service layer and map the result to your ViewModel object.

Using this aproach you can create an object with your view's properties and just bind it to your gridview and other controlls.

Your ViewModel object would look like this:

```
public class MyViewModelItem {
    public int LowHouse { get; set; }
    public int HighHouse { get; set; }
    public char Side { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel {
    // Your other view's properties

    public List<MyViewModelItem> List { get; set; }
}
```

And your controller like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public MyController()
    {
        myService = new MyService(); // Consider Dependency Injection
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        var data = myService.List();
        var myModel = MapMyModel(data);

        return View(myModel);
    }

    private MyViewModel MapMyModel(IEnumerable<YOUR_ENTITY> data) {
        var myModel = new MyViewModel();
        myModel.List = new List<MyViewModelItem>();

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            myModel.List.Add(new MyViewModelItem {
                LowHouse = item.ODD_LOW,
                HighHouse = item.ODD_HIGH,
                Side = [your logic]
            })
        }
    }
}
```

References:

1. [Use ViewModels to manage data & organize code in ASP.NET MVC applications](http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/)
2. [ASP.NET MVC View Model Patterns](https://stevemichelotti.com/aspnet-mvc-view-model-patterns/)

Comment: Fair enough. But It's existing functionality and I've just been tasked to update it as simply as possible, not re-engineer it. :) The model comes directly from the DB, and the classes that handle it are all in place. :/

Comment: I undestand that working with legacy code can be a pain. But as a professional programmer I still would go with the viewModel object aproach and might leave a service / business layer behind.